# Output of the following C code

Tags: c, arrays, endianness

What will be the output of the following C code. Assuming it runs on Little endian machine, where short int takes 2 Bytes and char takes 1 Byte.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    short int c[5];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        c[i] = 400 + i;
    char *b = (char *)c;
    printf("%d", *(b+8));
    return 0;
}
```

In my machine it gave

```
-108
```

I don't know if my machine is Little endian or big endian. I found somewhere that it should give

```
148
```

as the output. Because low order 8 bits of 404(i.e. element c[4]) is 148. But I think that due to "%d", it should read 2 Bytes from memory starting from the address of c[4].

Comment: compilation flag can change default char to signed / unsigned etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c[4]` stores `404`. In a two-byte little-endian representation, that means two bytes of `0x94` `0x01`, or (in decimal) `148` `1`.

`b+8` addresses the memory of `c[4]`. `b` is a pointer to `char`, so the `8` means adding 8 bytes (which is 4 two-byte shorts). In other words, `b+8` points to the first byte of `c[4]`, which contains `148`.

`*(b+8)` (which could also be written as `b[8]`) dereferences the pointer and thus gives you the value `148` as a `char`. What this does is implementation-defined: On many common platforms `char` is a signed type (with a range of `-128` .. `127`), so it can't actually be `148`. But if it is an unsigned type (with a range of `0` .. `255`), then `148` is fine.

The bit pattern for `148` in binary is `10010100`. Interpreting this as a two's complement number gives you `-108`.

This `char` value (of either `148` or `-108`) is then automatically converted to `int` because it appears in the argument list of a variable-argument function (`printf`). This doesn't change the value.

Finally, `"%d"` tells `printf` to take the `int` argument and format it as a decimal number.

So, to recap: Assuming you have a machine where

- a byte is 8 bits
- negative numbers use two's complement
- `short int` is 2 bytes

... then this program will output either `-108` (if `char` is a signed type) or `148` (if `char` is an unsigned type).

Answer (score 2):

The code gives different outputs on different computers because on some platforms the `char` type is signed by default and on others it's unsigned by default. That has nothing to do with endianness. Try this:

```
    char *b = (char *)c;
    printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)*(b+8)); // always prints 148 
    printf("%d\n", (signed char)*(b+8));   // always prints -108 (=-256 +148)
```

The default value is dependent on the platform and compiler settings. You can control the default behavior with GCC options `-fsigned-char` and `-funsigned-char`.

Answer (score 1):

To see what sizes types have in your system:

```
printf("char = %u\n", sizeof(char));    
printf("short = %u\n", sizeof(short));    
printf("int = %u\n", sizeof(int));    
printf("long = %u\n", sizeof(long));    
printf("long long = %u\n", sizeof(long long));
```

---

Change the lines in your program

```
unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *)c;
printf("%d\n", *(b + 8));
```

---

And simple test (I know that it is not guaranteed but all C compilers I know do it this way and I do not care about old CDC or UNISYS machines which had different addresses and pointers to different types of data

```
printf(" endianes test: %s\n", (*b + (unsigned)*(b + 1) * 0x100) ==  400? "little" : "big");
```

Another remark: it is only because in your program c[0] == 400